# Ubuntu equivalent to LaunchRocket

Tags: gui, services

LaunchRocket looks like a pretty nice software for managing services on MacOS ([source on github](https://github.com/jimbojsb/launchrocket)).

[Here is a screenshot of LaunchRocket](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jimbojsb/launchrocket/master/screenshots/LaunchRocket.png)

You can easily stop and start services from this app. So here is my question:

Does anyone know an equivalent gui on for Linux / Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use system-monitor (pre-installed), its closer to Windows task manager but can start/stop services

[image]

Or open a terminal and run

```
top
```

[image]

another I found is [Boot-Up Manager (BUM)](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-up-manager-bum-graphical-runlevel-editor.html) It looks simple, may suit your needs

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

I know it says boot up but can stop start services too.

There is also jobs-admin, says it is like bum but simpler

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jpeddicord/jobtools && apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jobs-admin jobservice
```

Can't find much about that one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But I am really looking for something more user friendly and which could eventually propose only process like mysql, apache, elasticsearch, etc.

Comment: Added to the answer

Comment: I dont understand why did you propose Nitro tasks. From what I can see, it's mainly a todo lists app. Did I miss something?

Comment: I found it on google, guess its the wrong type of "task manager" sorry.